# Подготовка запроса к базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatId = (:chatId) AND id < (:msgId) AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
    $stmt->bindParam(':chatId', $chatId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':msgId', $msgId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Данный код получает 20 сообщений с чата. Как получить 20 сообщений с непустым  `imgUrl`?

Comment: Добавить соотв. условие в секцию WHERE запроса (`AND imgUrl IS NOT NULL`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вот так:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatId = (:chatId) AND id < (:msgId) AND removeAt = 0 AND imgUrl <> '' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
$stmt->bindParam(':chatId', $chatId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':msgId', $msgId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если `imgUrl` это колонка в таблице, то надо добавить условие

```
imgUrl IS NOT NULL AND imgUrl != ''
```

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatId = (:chatId) AND id < (:msgId) AND removeAt = 0 AND (imgUrl IS NOT NULL AND imgUrl != '') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
```

UPD. По поводу двух условий.

Как заметил @Akina в данном случае и правда можно обойтись одной проверкой `!= ''`.

Я использую две по привычке от обратного сравнения, когда надо выбрать пустые поля, тогда все же необходимо 2 проверки.

Comment: Первое условие - избыточно. Если `imgUrl IS NULL`, то `imgUrl != ''` == `NULL` == `false`.

Comment: @Akina NULL и пустая строка - это две разные вещи

Comment: @rjhdby Ну да (и, кстати, не везде) - и что? как это влияет на сказанное мной?

Comment: @Akina да очень просто влияет. Если из  `imgUrl IS NOT NULL AND imgUrl != ''
` убрать первое условие, то возвратятся все записи, кроме пустых строк. В том числе и NULL

Comment: @rjhdby *В том числе и NULL* :facepalm: Учите матчасть! [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b189943b036379fd94b87226ea4033f)

Comment: @Akina Это частный случай поведения, свойственный далеко не всем БД. Вам бы самому матчасть подучить.

Comment: @rjhdby *Это частный случай поведения, свойственный далеко не всем БД.* 1) Вопрос помечен тегом MySQL - кивать на другие СУБД несколько не по делу. 2) Назовите, пожалуйста, конкретную СУБД, в которой сказанное мной - неверно.

Comment: @Akina вы правы - тег я как-то просмотрел. MS SQL c `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`

Comment: @rjhdby По умолчанию у SQL Server ANSI_NULLS = ON. Настройка в OFF - это такой же трик, как и null-safe compare у MySQL. Причём, в отличие от MySQL, который вводит специальный оператор, такая перенастройка - это сознательное отступление от стандарта.

Comment: @Akina ну ок, убедили :) Другой вопрос, что поведение это крайне не очевидное по сути своей. И если речь не о хайлоаде, то все-же имеет смысл  отдельно добавлять сравнение с пустой строкой кмк

Comment: @rjhdby *имеет смысл отдельно добавлять сравнение с пустой строкой* Эммм... так я именно его и предлагал оставить, а проверку на NULL, как избыточную, убрать.

Comment: @Akina имел в виду, что и то и то оставлять. Но это уже вкусовщина конечно.